# API call using file_get_contents() returns 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable, but returns fine in browser

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to return results from the chain.so blockchain API. When I make an API call with the URL https://chain.so/api/v2/get_tx_received/BTC/3Mk6mNxzXJQegkc276N2pCMRwWHMpMjgbP

The results show correctly in a web browser.

I get the following error in PHP:

Warning: file_get_contents(https://chain.so/api/v2/get_tx_received/BTC/3Mk6mNxzXJQegkc276N2pCMRwWHMpMjgbP): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/test/chainso-api.php on line 8

Code I'm using:

```
$url = "https://chain.so/api/v2/get_tx_received/BTC/3Mk6mNxzXJQegkc276N2pCMRwWHMpMjgbP";

$content = file_get_contents($url);        
echo $content;
```

I have also tried using cURL, but can't get results to return using it either. I have noticed cloudflare is used on the API, could that be preventing the results from being returned?

Comment: The administrator of that site must open API to the public. Otherwise, you cannot do anything.

Comment: You can check the trafic with fiddler and you will find there have some check redict.

Answer (score 0):

The chain.so API was put offline for a couple off months due to spam attacks as founder of SoChain.com statet on reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/dogecoin/comments/cqttm7/chainso_api_and_python_cryptos_module/

However it is online again today, without any visible changes to their API or any new notifications.